# ANTLR4: what design pattern to follow?

Tags: antlr4

I have a ANTR4 rule "expression" that can be either "maths" or "comparison", but "comparison" can contain "maths". Here a concrete code:

```
expression
    : ID
    | maths
    | comparison
    ;

maths
    : maths_atom ((PLUS | MINUS) maths_atom) ? // "?" because in fact there is first multiplication then pow and I don't want to force a multiplication to make an addition
    ;

maths_atom
    : NUMBER
    | ID
    | OPEN_PAR expression CLOSE_PAR
    ;

comparison
    : comp_atom ((EQUALS | NOT_EQUALS) comp_atom) ?
    ;

comp_atom
    : ID
    | maths // here is the expression of interest
    | OPEN_PAR expression CLOSE_PAR
    ;
```

If I give, for instance, `6` as input, this is fine for the parse tree, because it detects `maths`. But in the ANTLR4 plugin for *Intellij Idea*, it mark my `expression` rule as red - ambiguity. Should I say goodbye to a short parse tree and allow only `maths` trough `comparison` in `expression` so it is not so ambiguous anymore ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the parser sees `6`, which is a `NUMBER`, it has two paths of reaching it through your grammar:

```
 expression - maths - maths_atom - NUMBER
```

or

```
 expression - comparison - comp_atom - NUMBER
```

This ambiguity triggers the error that you see.

You can fix this by flattening your parser grammar [as shown in this tutorial](https://keyholesoftware.com/2020/01/21/an-antlr4-based-expression-parser/):

```
start
    : expr | <EOF>
    ;
    
expr
    : expr (PLUS | MINUS) expr         # ADDGRP
    | expr (EQUALS | NOT_EQUALS) expr  # COMPGRP
    | OPEN_PAR expression CLOSE_PAR    # PARENGRP
    | NUMBER                           # NUM
    | ID                               # IDENT
    ;
```

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, there is no "NUMBER" in comparison. I edited the question.

Comment: By the way, my grammar is too complex to get flatten like this. Read my first command in the code

Comment: @bananasmoothii Then `ID` is the problem: you can reach it directly or through a sequence of rules. Either way, the flattened grammar can recognize your original syntax, i.e. it would let you put an `ID` by itself.

Comment: Yes, that's the question. should I only allow it through a sequence of rules, but that would make some weird-looking parse trees, or make good parse trees and allow it directly

Comment: @Bananasmoothii There is no clean way around it, because you have no markers in the text that would let you tell apart a math expression consisting of a single `ID` from an expression that represents a single `ID` by itself. Usually it does not matter, because your visitor can ignore all intermediate single-child nodes.